# How can I use percent in a LIKE clause in JPA/Play Framework?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to find all Users whose email contain the string `middle` somewhere inside.

The following code fails - it seems JPA doesn't recognize the `?` as a parameter because its enclosed by quotation marks.

```
List<User> users = User.findAll("email like '%?%'", middle);
```

The following code works, but is open to SQL injections:

```
List<User> users = User.findAll("email like '%" + middle + "%'");
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your string manipulation to the Java side, and keep the SQL parameter:

```
List<User> users = User.findAll("email like ?", "%"+middle+"%");
```

Comment: Great idea, why didn't I think of that!